# Linker error with ffmpeg

Tags: qt, linker, ffmpeg

I'm trying to build a really simple Qt program using [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) library.

Currently I just want to open and close a video file.

Here is my project file:

```
QT    += core gui
TARGET = avtest01
TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

And my code:

```
#include <QDebug>

extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        AVFormatContext *format_context;
        qDebug() << argv[1];
        if(avformat_open_input(&format_context, argv[1], NULL, NULL) == 0)
        {
            qDebug() << "open";
            avformat_close_input(&format_context);
        }
        else
            qDebug() << "error opening " << argv[1];
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the linker fails:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "avformat_open_input(AVFormatContext**, char const*, AVInputFormat*, AVDictionary**)", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
  "avformat_close_input(AVFormatContext**)", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
```

I'm using Qt 5.1.0 on MacOS.

Comment: I am getting the same issue when I call `avformat_open_input`. What did you do to resolve the issue? How differently did you build *FFmpeg* for MacOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked for me after I added `av_register_all();` to main.

My guess is that you have avformat compiled for 32 bit. You can confirm by running `file /usr/local/lib/libavformat.dylib` in terminal.

The output should look like:

```
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Comment: I had to link other libraries but I think this is due to the ffmpeg compilation I made (from http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide)

Comment: @MartinDelille What did you do different wrt to build *FFmpeg* for MacOS? I am using static builds using the script from [here](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script). I get the same linker error when calling `avformat_open_input`

Comment: Just use home-brew to install on osx.